# using a different IP for webservice calls

Tags: php, windows, web-services, iis-7, iis-8

Scenario - multiple computers at site (db, app, report etc)   all systems are functioning right now using the assigned IP address from customer.

New twist is this - the system that generates the web service calls to external data providers (state run websites) needs to originate the traffic from a different IP address.  The new IP address is the only one that is allowed to go through the firewall, the internal data traffic will stay inside the enclave of systems, communicating with each other.  The same machine (app server) is the interface with the user using a webserver, having two (or more) IP addresses assigned to it.

Here is the question - in the code, is there a way to have the web service originator call to use a different IP address to communicate with the outside world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be difficult to implement through httpclient, but [HttpWebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=net-5.0) can help you if you use asp.net.

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://stackoverflow.com");

        System.Net.WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("the IP", 80);
        request.Proxy = proxy;
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply - do you have any additional information on what parameters need to be changed to facilitate this operation

Comment: I add the sample code in the answer now, you can refer to it.